# Prolog not showing output in the way I want / need

Tags: list, prolog

I am pretty new to Prolog and need to solve a task. So I need to compare two lists and check if they have the same length and contain an odd number of elements. I´m only allowed to use following build in operators: ! and fail.

The code works so far but when I want to get following from Prolog:

```
guu([a,b,c],X).
```

I get this:

```
X = [_900, _906, _912]
```

but what I want is this:

```
X = [a, b, c]
```

or:

```
X = [a , a, a]
```

My code so far:

```
guu([_],[_]):- !.
guu([_,_],[_,_]):- fail, !.
guu([],[]):- fail, !.
guu([],[_]):- fail, !.
guu([_],[]):- fail, !.
guu([_,_|Tail1], [_,_|Tail2]):- guu(Tail1,Tail2).
```

I think I messed something up with the "_" operator but idk :/

Fixed it with:

```
guu([H|T],[H|T]):-!. 
guu([_],[_]):- !.
guu([_,_],[_,_]):- fail, !.
guu([],[]):- fail, !.
guu([],[_]):- fail, !.
guu([_],[]):- fail, !.
guu([_,_|Tail1], [_,_|Tail2]):- guu(Tail1,Tail2),!.
```

Comment: Every `_` is unique. When you say `guu([_], [_])` you are literally saying any two one-item lists are related by guu. What you probably mean is `guu([X], [X]).` Similarly for your other uses of `_`. Reserve `_` for situations where you really mean that there is no _relationship_ between that variable and any other.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. I already got it to work :)

Comment: If you have a solution, feel free to post it and accept it below.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with:

```
guu([H|T],[H|T]):-!.
```